# Are Texture2D size limits area related or dimension related?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating an Image Data Base containing a number of small (~150 x 150) images that will be used as Sprite textures.  Currently I create the atlas image as a long strip. (n W x H where n = number of images, W is each image width and H is each image height).  I was reading that there are size limits such as 4k x 4k for Texture2D.  I know most textures are square or nearly so.  In this case, I could end up with a 64k x 100 image. ~6M pixels is smaller than the 16M of a 4k x 4K image by area but one dimension is definitely larger than 4k.

So what I want to know is:

Are Texture2D size limits area related or dimension related?

Comment: Please leave your question at the end of the text. It will also be very helpful for other users if you post your code and use formatting correctly. If you follow these rules and do your research beforehand you will save your soul from downvotes in further instances! Ps. Pictures are always fun! Welcome to Stackoverfow!

Comment: Texture size is limited by the capabilities of the video card your application is being run on. That is also why they should be a power of two and square, because that is what the video hardware requires. We restrict our atlases to 2k x 2k because the mobile hardware we run on does not always support 4k x 4k.

Answer (score 0):

## Its size based

i.e. *literally* 4k pixels wide and 4k pixels tall (or rather, 4096 pixels, exactly).

Power-of-2 textures can be compressed much more easily than non-power-of-2 textures, along with mip-map scaling (only works on power of 2) and other features that make them nicer for GPU streaming and storage.

Rewriting your algorithms to handle your atlas shouldn't be too hard; converting from 1D to 2D array indices are a very common Programmer Interview Question and you should be able to work it out on paper in about 5 minutes (or Google it in 45 seconds ;).